# How to convert a string in a format that is listed into a list in python

Tags: python

How would you convert a string such as `"[[5, 3, 0.92], [4, 5, 0.3]]"` into a list in a list format such as

```
data = [[5, 3, 0.92], [4, 5, 0.3)]
print(data[0]
>>> [5, 3, 0.92]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `[[5, 3, 0.92], [4, 5, 0.3)]]` is invalid syntax because of the unmatched closing parenthesis

Comment: you might be interested in knowing about [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: When trying to strip or split it printing data[0] only a parenthesis is printing, also tried using eval(), but that didnt work either

Comment: If the syntax is actually correct and you just made typos when copying here, use `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri You might be interested in knowing about [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). It should be preferred when you don't need the full power of `eval()`.

Comment: Given that your example is a JSON like object you could do something like `json.loads("[[5, 3, 0.92], [4, 5, 0.3]]")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = eval("[[5, 3, 0.92], [4, 5, 0.3]]")
data[0]
>>> [5, 3, 0.92]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `json.loads`. Its built to deal with things like this exactly.

```py
import json
li = "[[5, 3, 0.92], [4, 5, 0.3]]"
print(json.loads(li))
```

Btw, You made a mistake in forming a valid string

Comment: Thanks, I found out "json.dumps(your_list_name)" also converts the list back to string if needed.